# How to apply CSS transitions to components in V-For

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I am new to adding animations with vue and I've become a bit unstuck. Here is my code rendering a list of components, one below the other. I want a button to appear beneath each one which when clicked will slide out one component and slide in the next. Currently, there is no button or component rendered and no errors. I don't know where I went wrong:

```js
<div class="row justify-content-center">            
            <transition-group
            name="custom-classes-transition"
            enter-active-class="animated bounceOutRight"
            leave-active-class="animated bounceOutRight">
                <div v-if="show">
                    <AppQuestionComponent
                    v-for="(section, index) in sections"
                    :key="section.id"
                    :index=index 
                    :header="section.name" 
                    :questions="section.question" 
                    v-on:sectionScore="sectionScoreChange"
                    ></AppQuestionComponent>      
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="show = !show">Next</button> 
                </div>  
            </transition-group>    
</div>
```

Comment: What css framework? Looks like bootstrap?

Comment: I'm sorry yes it's bootstrap

Comment: I have not worked much with transitions, and never with group transitions, But this looks like a good reasource: https://medium.com/@msanathkumar/understanding-transitions-and-animations-in-vuejs-115a0f5c6fbc#1f6b and obv the docs https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions

Comment: Probably https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Between-Components would be helpful.

Comment: If nothing's being rendered it probably means `sections` isn't populated with any data. Could you post the code for this?

Comment: Either that or `show` isn't evaluating to true initially

Comment: For your original question, sounds like you'd be better off using a data property `index` then incrementing it on click, triggering the transition.